# How can i change the color of my panel by a button

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, backcolor

How can I change the color of my panel by a button! I want to change the back color of my panel to this **RGB color 51, 51, 51**.
How I can make a **button** to change BackColor of the panel.

Comment: `panel1.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb(51, 51, 51)` -- or something like that. It's from memory

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Button1_Click(object o, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 51, 51, 51);
}
```

Add this code to your ***Button click*** event.

**Note:: Change panel1 name if required.**